# how compiler select which "get_pc_thunk" function to get current address?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, register-allocation, position-independent-code

PIE binary use the function `__x86.get_pc_thunk` to get address dynamically defined at loading time.

i) Sometime it calls `__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax`.

```
5ff:   e8 24 00 00 00          call   628 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
604:   05 fc 19 00 00          add    $0x19fc,%eax
609:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
60c:   8d 90 b0 e6 ff ff       lea    -0x1950(%eax),%edx
612:   52                      push   %edx
613:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
615:   e8 36 fe ff ff          call   450 <printf@plt>
```

ii)  Sometime it calls `__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx`.

```
634:   e8 87 fe ff ff          call   4c0  <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
639:   81 c3 c7 19 00 00       add    $0x19c7,%ebx
63f:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
642:   8b 6c 24 20             mov    0x20(%esp),%ebp
646:   8d b3 f0 fe ff ff       lea    -0x110(%ebx),%esi
64c:   e8 cb fd ff ff          call   41c <_init>
```

iii) And sometimes It calls `__x86.get_pc_thunk.cx` or sometimes `__x86.get_pc_thunk.dx`.

I know difference between `__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx` and `__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax` is  the register, that store return address in, `.bx` to `EBX`, `.ax` to `EAX`.

**Then, my question is :**

how compiler select which function to use among   `__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax`/`__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx`/`__x86.get_pc_thunk.cx`/`__x86.get_pc_thunk.dx`?

Is it selected truly random at compile time?
Or is there any algorithm for select that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler selects the appropriate function for whatever register it wants to use.  Which register is used is the result of the compiler's *register allocation* for the function it compiles and is generally not predictable.

Comment: I see.. Thank you for your answer.